# Add and Remove items between controls asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, transfer

Right now I currently have a `ListView` with a `datasourceid` linked to a small database of `names/id#(identity)`. I want the functionality to be that when you select a name, it gets added into another control (like a table of some sort). Then, you should be able to click it in that table, and it'll add back to the `ListView`. I was just wondering if there were any particular controls that would make this simpler? I need to be able to "pair" these names as well. So "person 1 goes with person 2". Drag and drop would be fantastic, but I really don't know the best way to go about implemeting that.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do. When you clicked on Person1, it appears in the second table and disappears from `ListView`? And you want to be able to swap Person1? And I don't understand the pairing. You want to be able to move multiple person at the same time?

Comment: No, don't need to move multiple people. There are many ways I could go about doing this.... but there needs to be some sort of text taht says "person 1 is paired up with person 2". That sort of thing. So after dragging two people over to another control, then it "pairs" them and says something like person 1 is paired with person 2.

Answer (score 0):

For the drag and drop functionality, [JQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) is the [way to go](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/). You'd need to initiate an Ajax request to a Web Service method or a Page Method, do the backend processing and modify your HTML markup.

Here's a [wonderful tutorial](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx) explaining how to call Web service methods from JQuery.

Comment: Cheers! Another quick question - would you suggest that when I switch between the two listviews, I utilize something like List<> to do the adding/removal, or should I directly alter the database? I really don't want to directly alter the database, it seems too costly.

Comment: @OhMisterRabbit: "I really don't want to directly alter the database, it seems too costly" --> I think this is, in general, a misconception. Altering (by this, I assume you mean CRUD operations) the database is *generally* quick but of course it depends on your tables, indexes, network topology, etc. Without knowing your requirements and your typical application's load is difficult to say, but I wouldn't be afraid to do this on the database, if needed.

Comment: Just a very basic delete from database function. that way it doesn't display in the listview anymore. I have way too many ideas on how to do this, and I can't crack down on just one way.